# What is the best way to handle browser back button for dynamic content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sails.js

We currently have an app (sails/node js), where the user is displayed a set of items which are dynamically produced. The user has the option to produce more dynamic items (using a button) or can preview one item (new page). Currently, the more items button is implemented as a jquery add-on implementing a post request.

The issue is, when the user clicks the more items button and selects one item for preview, and then presses the browser back button, the dynamic content is lost.

We see different options:
1. Implement pagination and infinite scroll and use history js to manage back button
2. Use history with the current set up and combine with jquery to manage back button.

Are there any other approach? Any help appreciated. We are totally new to this development environment.

Comment: localStorage might help https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage a [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API):

```
var stateObj = { lastItemId: 456 }; // or { page: 3 }
history.pushState(stateObj, "page 2", "bar.html");
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I found was to "disable" back button clicks.  Ok, technically, there's no way to disable it, but you can give the end user the appearance that the back button has been disabled.  I originally developed my code based on [this blog post](http://jordanhollinger.com/2012/06/08/disable-the-back-button-using-html5).  It's a good read as he explains the approach in detail.  Since then, I've refined his code as detailed below.

So I define `preventBackButton ()` like this.

```
function preventBackButton () {
    // Triggered when the back button is pressed, it will detect if the url hash changes from #rms to #no-back.  If it does, then
    // it harmlessly changes the url hash forward again by going from "#no-back" to "#rms".

    // On initial page load, pushes states "#no-back" and "#rms" onto the history, making it the most recent "page" to detect future "back" button presses.
    var history_api = typeof history.pushState !== 'undefined';

    if ( history_api ) {
        history.pushState(null, '', '#no-back');
        history.pushState(null, '', '#rms');
    } else {
        location.hash = '#no-back';
        location.hash = '#rms';
    }

    // This function creates an event handler on hash changes.  This is coded to detect back button clicks.
    window.onhashchange = function() {
        // location.hash becomes "#no-back" when the user clicks back button
        if ( location.hash === '#no-back' ) {
            if ( history_api ) {
                history.pushState(null, '', '#rms');
            } else {
                location.hash = '#rms';
            }
        } 
    };

} // function preventBackButton ()
```

Then I call it in `$(document).ready()`

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    preventBackButton();
    // Do other stuff...

});
```